# Eliminating duplicate record in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So how to eliminate duplicate record?

```
select distinct top 10  Name, prd.productId, prd.SellStartDate,salesOrderID,
Name,ProductNumber,StandardCost,UnitPrice,OrderQty 
from SalesLT.Product as prd
INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as sale
on prd.ProductID=sale.ProductID
where 
prd.SellStartDate between '07/01/ 1998' and '01/01/2007'
and prd.ProductNumber is not null
and prd.Color in('Black','White')
order by prd.SellStartDate
```

[image]

Comment: Respect  Gurv,  can you explain how to eliminate duplicate . Output of above query is:-

Comment: Output :- 738 2001-07-01 00:00:00.000 71783 LL Road Frame - Black, 52 LL Road Frame - Black, 52 FR-R38B-52 204.6251 202.332 4
738 2001-07-01 00:00:00.000 71797 LL Road Frame - Black, 52 LL Road Frame - Black, 52 FR-R38B-52 204.6251 202.332 1
738 2001-07-01 00:00:00.000 71815 LL Road Frame - Black, 52 LL Road Frame - Black, 52 FR-R38B-52 204.6251 202.332 1

Comment: Your DISTINCT query should fail if the ORDER BY field [SellStartDate] is not included in the result set. What code are you actually running?

Comment: Hi Pacreely, please see the above query and his result.

Comment: We really need to see some sample input data, the **exact** query your are running and the current and desired output to understand your problem and help you resolve it.

Comment: For what it's worth though, as best I can tell if you only want to see one row per `productId`, then you need to aggregate the fields from `SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail` using a `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte AS
    (
    select 
        Name
        , prd.productId
        , prd.SellStartDate
        , salesOrderID
        , Name
        , ProductNumber
        , StandardCost
        , UnitPrice
        , OrderQty 
        , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY prd.SellStartDate ORDER BY salesOrderID) AS Rnk
    from 
        SalesLT.Product as prd
            INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as sale
                ON 
                prd.ProductID=sale.ProductID 
    WHERE 
        prd.SellStartDate between '07/01/1998' and '01/01/2007' 
        AND 
        prd.ProductNumber is not null 
        AND 
        prd.Color in('Black','White') 
    )
SELECT distinct top 10  
        Name
        , productId
        , SellStartDate
        , salesOrderID
        , Name
        , ProductNumber
        , StandardCost
        , UnitPrice
        , OrderQty 
FROM
    cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER by 
    SellStartDate
```

Comment: Thank you pacreely,The column 'Name' was specified multiple times for 'cte'. Now it resolve. can you explain " RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY prd.SellStartDate ORDER BY salesOrderID) AS Rnk"

Comment: AJIT AGARWAL: It wasn't 100% clear what you were asking, but it looked like you wanted records with no Duplicate values in specific columns. The rank() example ensures a single row from each sellstartdate is pulled back and creates the level of Distinct that you wan't, but without being able to see the Uniqueness of your source data I've made some guesses. Did it work for you?

Comment: AJIT AGARWAL: That's great, don't forget to accept the answer.